# How to create Desktop shortcut for react native windows based Application

Tags: react-native-windows

I'm using React native windows using visual studio I'm able to create (.appxbundle) file.
this bundle I can install but it will not create desktop icon (desktop shortcut).
is there any way to do it.

```
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"react-native-windows": "0.59.0-legacy.2",
```